# Horizontal bar chart by ios-charts

Tags: xcode, ios-charts

How to create horizontal bar chart by ios-charts in xcode?
I created View with class HorizontalBarChartView

```
@IBOutlet weak var horChart: HorizontalBarChartView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0]

    setChart(months, values: unitsSold)

}

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: chartDataSet)
    horChart.data = chartData

}
```

Didnt find any examples in the Internet

Answer (score 6):

Check your horChart view in mainStoryboard. is class is"HorizontalBarChartView" and module is "Charts", 
Same problem I was faced but my problem is resolved by set module is "Charts"

Answer (score 0):

There is exmaples in the ChartsDemo folder, and there are lots of charts you can take a look. But I will paste the code here, it's copied from `@interface HorizontalBarChartViewController`:

```
- (void)setDataCount:(int)count range:(double)range
{
    NSMutableArray *xVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        [xVals addObject:months[i % 12]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *yVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        double mult = (range + 1);
        double val = (double) (arc4random_uniform(mult));
        [yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:val xIndex:i]];
    }

    BarChartDataSet *set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yVals label:@"DataSet"];
    set1.barSpace = 0.35;

    NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [dataSets addObject:set1];

    BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xVals dataSets:dataSets];
    [data setValueFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:10.f]];

    _chartView.data = data;
}
```

Comment: While converting this code into Swift, there got many syntax error.

Comment: that's your problem.. not the code. You should get yourself familiar with swift and Objc first.

Comment: agreed! but there is such a difference between version 3 and 2.3 its a shock and the demos are not much help as they refer to version 2. So I've spent ages converting my project to version 3. For us beginner/intermediate programmers its a mountain to climb. Just trying to change the label colours for valueColors has cost me hours as its depreciated and i'm left with black text on a grey background.

Comment: it just redesign X axis in chart 3 and some refactor. if you already knew v2, it should not be that hard. there is release notes as well.

Comment: how can i create line chart horizontally?